# Find $f_W$ for $W=-\frac{1}{2}\log(X)$. Given answer doesn't match my answer

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

> Let $X$ a random variable with the p.d.f.
>
> $$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
> 3x^2, & \text{if } 0<x<1 \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> and $W=-\frac{1}{2}\log(X) $. Find the p.d.f. $f_W$ for $W$.

I've been given this task and the answer to the question as well. So, my idea was to use the formula:

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(x_1)}{g'(x_1)}$$

where $\ g(x_1)=y$.

However, the answer that I am ending up with simply does not align with the answer given by the instructor. I am told that the answer should be $W \sim \operatorname{Exp}(6) $.

This is how I'm breaking the task down:

$$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
3x^2, & \text{if } 0<x<1 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
g(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\log(x)$$

are given by the task. So what I need to do is differentiate $g(x)$ and find the inverse function of $W$ and put it all together:

- Derivative: $g'(x) = -\frac{1}{2x} $.
- Inverse: $x_1 = g^{-1}(x) = e^{-2x}$.

Putting it together:

$$ f_W(x)
= \frac{3 \cdot (e^{-2x})^2}{-1/(2 \cdot e^{-2x})}
=-6(e^{-2x})^3 $$

As you can see this doesn't match the given answer. I've used hours trying other methods but cannot find the mistake. Any thoughts?

Best regards

Comment: Try using mathjax more properly to make your work more presentable. You can also use it in the title.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that mathjax worked in the title as well. I'll edit it.

Comment: You can put the function $f_X$ in the body and make the title something like find $f_W$ if $W=...$

Comment: The title seems a bit messy.

Comment: Thank's for the input guys. I've edited the title using mathjax and reduced the information given in the title.

Comment: I edited the question so that it is more readable. Hope this did not harm your intention of the question.

Comment: Thats very kind of you. Thank you. I'll try to make the questions clearer in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cdf of  $W$ can be calsulated as follows

$$F_W(w)=P(W<w)=P\left(-\frac12\log(X)<w\right)=$$
$$=P\left(\log(X)>-2w\right)=P\left(X>e^{-2w}\right)=$$
$$=3\int_{e^{-2w}}^1x^2\ dx=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if } &w<0\\1-e^{-6w}&\text{ if } &0\leq w.\end{cases}$$

The density is then

$$f_W(w)=\frac{d F_W}{dw}=6e^{-6w}$$

if $w\geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very understandable explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The pdf of $W$ can be written as
$$
f_W(w)=\int_0^1 dx\ 3x^2\delta\left(w+\frac{1}{2}\ln x\right)\ ,
$$
using a Dirac delta. Since $w+(1/2)\ln x=0\Rightarrow x=e^{-2w}$, we have
$$
f_W(w)=\int_0^1 dx\ 3x^2\frac{\delta\left(x-e^{-2w}\right)}{\frac{1}{2e^{-2w}}}=6e^{-2w}\times e^{-4w}\mathbb{1}(e^{-2w}<1)=6e^{-6 w}\theta(w)\ ,
$$
which is correctly normalized over $w\in (0,\infty)$. The fact that the support is $(0,\infty)$ is evident from the definition, as the $\log$ of a number $X$ between $0$ and $1$ is negative. I think all you are missing is the absolute value of $g'(x)$.

PS I highly doubt that your instructor gave you $w\sim e(6)$ as a solution. That notation doesn't make any sense, to start with...

Comment: Thank you very much! The Dirac delta notation is unknown to me but you are totally correct in the numerical value mistake, and your reply was very helpful. I promise that it was the answer the instructor gave. He must have written an answer to a different exercise on the paper then. He owes me 2 hours of my life :-).

Comment: You are welcome! I can suggest some further reading (e.g. http://ece.iisc.ernet.in/~yrv/past-papers/A5_1.pdf and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.520.6221&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for the delta function method for computing pdfs of functions of random variable. It takes some initial effort to understand the method, but then it is really powerful and general!

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. That's very kind of you. I'll definitely read up on that method!

Answer (score 1):

Let $w\in (0,\infty)$. Let $F_W$ be the CDF of of $W$ and $F_X$ the CDF of $X$

\begin{align}
F_W(w)&=P(W<w)=P\left(\frac{-\ln(X)}{2}<w\right)\\
&=P(\ln(X)>-2w)=P(X>e^{-2w})\\&
=1-P(X\leq e^{-2w})=1-F_X(e^{-2w})
\end{align}
Differentiating and using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives us the pdf of $W$. So:
\begin{align}
f_W(w)=2e^{-2w}f_X(e^{-2w})=2e^{-2w}3e^{-4w}=6e^{-6w}
\end{align}
since $w\in(0,\infty)$. It can be easily seen that $f_W(w)=0$ for $w\leq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Im really impressed with the forum. 3 answers that are all very helpful!